# Configure Easyphp to process htm files as php

Tags: php, easyphp

On my remote server I'm using the line
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html`
to parse the php in files with htm/html extensions
How can I replicate this behaviour on my local machine running EasyPHP.
I have tried adding the same line to Apache/conf/httpd.conf and restarting the server, but the files are displayed as html files, without the php code running.

Various googles/php docs/stack/easyphp doc searches have failed to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add the same line in the conf_files/httpd.conf
since the apache/conf/httpd.conf is regenerate each time you start your server.